# Replacing while-loop with recursion

Tags: c#, sockets, recursion, while-loop, tcpclient

Quick and simple question:

Is this:

```
private static void SetupConnection()
{
    try
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(myServer, myPort);
        //Do whatever...
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        //Server is closed. Retry in 10 minutes.
        Thread.Sleep(600000);
        SetupConnection();
    }
```

a viable alternative to this:

```
private static void SetupConnection()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(myServer, myPort);
            //Do whatever...
            break;
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            //Server is closed. Retry in 10 minutes.
            Thread.Sleep(600000);
        }
    }
}
```

While the second one looks "cleaner" I am still rather curious if the first one is also acceptable – and if it isn't, then why not?

Comment: In general, it's better to avoid recursion. If the connection keeps failing, you'll eventually blow the stack. It's also a bit easier to keep track of things like how many times you've tried to reconnect with a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why Recursion is Bad ?**

You will need to understand what is call stack.

This is a stack which is maitained in the memory.  Every time a new method is called, that method's reference and parmaeters are added in this stack.  This stack will be maintained in memory (RAM).

With recursion, if you keep on calling method without any boundary condition, the stack will keep on growing.

After some time, it would be in a state where it cannot accept any further entries because there is not enough memory to hold it.

That's when you will get "Stack Overflow Exception".

**Can we rewrite every recursive algorithm without using recursion ?**

Yes you can.  The aproach is generally called as "Iterative approach".

In every case, you can use an auxillary stack  / list / group of variables - to hold the parameters you were using in recursion.

Then you can iterate over these variables, until you reach the boundary condition.

That way, you can achieve the same result without calling your method again and again.
It is always better to use this approach.

**Then why people write recursive algorithms ?**

Sometimes, recursive algorithm is very easy to read.  Iterative approach code may not be easy to read and that's why people try to write recursive code many times.

You can decide whether to use iterative approach or recursive approach based on two things:

- Input samples
- Code maintainability

If you still want to write recursive method, DO NOT forget to add the boundary condition after which recursion will stop.

For ex. Tree travesal code (pre order, in order , post order) is easier to understand if you write recursive algorithm. 
This will work fine as long as you have some limit on number of nodes / levels in the tree.    If you already know that your tree is very huge, probably you would go for iterative aproach.

Hope this helps you to understand these approaches better.

Comment: Don't forget that recursive algorithms are often easier to write - otherwise you need to manage your own stack to keep your data.  If you don't do it properly, you can easily eliminate the overhead of method calls.  Recursion is here to stay.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I only want to add the following consideration. Since the depth of a balanced binary tree is `log2(N)`, the stack grows much slower than the number of tree nodes. For unbalanced trees, the worst case is a depth of `N`, i.e. it basically degrades to a linear list. A comparable worst-case behavior can also occur for Quicksort and other algorithms. Therefore, always carefully consider the worst-case scenario.

Answer (score 6):

Recursion is bad in this case, because if your program runs for too long and connection is retried, you will eventually hit a StackOverflowException.